# how to store the json file in container in azure storage account using bicep module @ API version: 2021-06-01

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-bicep

I have created the container in storage account. Need to add the template.json file in that cointainer.

I have created Container named 'mycontainer' in Azure storage account , trying to store the template.json file in the container.

```
resource container 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-09-01' = {
  name: 'mycontainer'
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    storageAccount
  ]
}

resource template 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs@2021-09-01' = {
  name: '${container.name}/template.json'
  properties: {
    contentType: 'application/json'
    source: './template.json'
  }
  dependsOn: [
    container
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look to leverage the [Azure DeploymentScripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template) resource.

It will be created during the bicep deployment process, but it runs script code  in your environment. As such it can bridge the control and data planes.

It's not suitable for every scenario, but it does facilitate complex scenarios. The bicep registry has a number of referenceable modules that show what is possible. https://azure.github.io/bicep-registry-modules/#deployment-scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can't store it using a bicep template. You can create the Storage Account and the container, but the template does not allow you to create blobs in it. There's also no documentation about creating blobs in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/blobservices/containers?pivots=deployment-language-bicep).

As alternative you could look into the Azure CLI, which integrates quite easily into many different pipelines. Using `az storage blob upload` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload)) you can upload your template file.